# How to stop long clicks being handled as short click when no context menu shown

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a list view which has been registered for a context menu. For some items within the list a context menu is not applicable. In these cases I just don't inflate a menu in the onCreateContextMenu method.

Unfortunately this means that when items that don't display a context menu are long-clicked Android then handles this as a short-click (presumably because the context menu would normally return true to say that the long-click event has been handled).

This results in an inconsistent behaviour in the listview - some items show a context menu when you long click them - others don't and then perform the default click behaviour. How can I ensure that even items that don't display a context menu consume the long click so that the onItemClick method isn't called?

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
  Playable playable = (Playable) info.targetView.getTag(R.id.playable);
  if (playable != null && !(playable instanceof AutoRadioStation) && !(playable.getId().equals(Playlist.AUTOMATIC_PLAYLIST))) {
    v.setTag(R.id.playable, playable); // This copies the tag so that it is contained within the view used for the menu.
    Drawable stationImage = (Drawable) ((ImageView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.artwork)).getDrawable().getConstantState().newDrawable();

    menu.setHeaderTitle(playable.getName());
    menu.setHeaderIcon(stationImage);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.saved_context_menu, menu);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got around to implementing a version of NathanZ solution. There didn't seem to be much stuff out there about turning a contextMenu into a DialogFragment so I'll paste most of my solution here.

Implementing an onLongItemClick listener also meant that I was able to have a long-click event that didn't require a menu within the listview. Unfortunately because you can't pass menus around to a dialog I had to reuse an existing ListViewElement type to store an id and a text string for each "menu" item in my listview.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int item, long position) {

    Playable playable = (Playable) view.getTag(R.id.playable);
    //Switch haptic feedback off by default so if we don't handle the long click we don't vibrate
    parent.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);

    if (playable == null) {
      // This must be a message bar so the only option is to update all saved content
      updateAll();
      parent.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
    } else {
      if (!(playable instanceof AutoRadioStation) && !(playable.getId().equals(Playlist.AUTOMATIC_PLAYLIST))) {
        Drawable drawable = (Drawable) ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.artwork)).getDrawable().getConstantState().newDrawable();
        showContextDialog(playable, drawable);
        parent.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  private void showContextDialog(Playable playable, Drawable drawable) {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    final List<ListViewElement> array = new ArrayList<ListViewElement>();
    array.add(new ListViewElement(R.id.menu_share, null, getString(R.string.share), true));
    array.add(new ListViewElement(R.id.menu_delete, null, getString(R.string.delete), true));
    ContextMenuDialog dialog = new ContextMenuDialog(drawable, playable.getName(), array, playable);
    dialog.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    dialog.show(fm, "Context Menu");
  }

  //Callback from the ContextMenuDialog class
  @Override
  public void onItemClickDialogFragment(int option, Playable playable) {
    switch (option) {
      case R.id.menu_delete :
        // Perform delete actions
        break;
      case R.id.menu_share :
        // Perform share actions
        break;
    }
  }


public class ContextMenuDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

  private Drawable drawableIcon;
  private String title;
  private List<ListViewElement> values;
  private Playable playable;
  private DialogFragmentOnItemClickListener listener;

  public interface DialogFragmentOnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClickDialogFragment(int option, Playable playable);
  }

  public void setOnItemClickListener(DialogFragmentOnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Create the dialog without a title since the layout includes a customized title
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialogStyle);
  }

  public ContextMenuDialog(Drawable drawableIcon, String title, List<ListViewElement> values, Playable playable) {
    this.drawableIcon = drawableIcon;
    this.title = title;
    this.values = values;
    this.playable = playable;
  }


  public ContextMenuDialog(int drawableResource, String title, List<ListViewElement> values, Playable playable) {
    this.drawableIcon = getResources().getDrawable(drawableResource);
    this.title = title;
    this.values = values;
    this.playable = playable;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.context_menu, container, true);
    TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_menu_title);
    titleView.setText(title);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_menu_artwork);
    icon.setImageDrawable(drawableIcon);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.context_menu_listview);
    ContextMenuAdapter adapter = new ContextMenuAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.context_menu_list_item, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I ended up using a [`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) instead of a context menu.

My activity implements [`OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html), and I show it from  `onLongItemClick()` if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: I had a look into that because that at least meant that I could return true from the OnItemLongClick in all cases. Do you have to create your own dialog or is there a way to invoke the normal context menu for the listview from the OnItemLongClickListener?

Comment: I don't think you can trigger the context menu directly, it is shown on long click when onCreateContextMenu is implemented. Unless I'm wrong, you must create your dialog which is a fairly easy process as you can see in the doc link I attached to my answer